# FileReader only reads the first two lines of TXT

Tags: java

I try to write a java program to read the user's input text and check the inputted text whether is duplicate or not. But I encounter a problem, FileReader only read the first two line of the specific TXT.
I've asked others for help, but they cannot figure out what's wrong! can anyone help me? THX!

PS If I type theodora, it will return the correct output. However if I type sophia, the other name in the txt file, it will return "Contact doesn't exist"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRuNo.png)

```
    Scanner fr1 = new Scanner (listFile);
    System.out.print ("Enter a contact name: ");

    inName = keyboard.nextLine ();
    
    if (!fr1.hasNext()){
        System.out.print ("Contact doesn't exist");
    }else{
        while (true){
            String strName = fr1.next();
            String strPhone = fr1.next();
            if (strName.equals(inName.trim())){
                System.out.print ("Contact name: " + strName+", Phone number: " + strPhone);
                keyboard.nextLine ();
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.print ("Contact doesn't exist");
                break;
            }
        }
    }fr1.close();
```

Comment: can you post a sample of how the txt file looks like? and also the contact that you want to find.

Comment: THX. I've uploaded the screenshot of the txt file

Comment: The problem is your loop not the `FileReader`. You always end the loop after the first run, because you have a `break` in each block of the if statement.

Comment: @SophiaTze Why did you upload a screen shot of the input instead of pasting the sample input?

Comment: In the while loop, you read the first two lines of the file and if the name isn't found, you break from the loop. You have to continue reading from `fr1` until it reaches the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can use List to store all the data from txt and then fetch the data out of it

```
{
    File file = new File(
            "\\Desktop\\test.txt");

    BufferedReader br
            = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String st;

    List contactList = new ArrayList();
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
        contactList.add(st);

    if(contactList.contains("Mona")){
        int index = contactList.indexOf("Mona");
        System.out.print ("Contact name: " + contactList.get(index)+", Phone number: " + contactList.get(index+1));
    }
}
```

**My txt contains :**
Tupan
123456
Mona
87546
Zen
97679

And **output** i am getting is
Contact name: Mona, Phone number: 87546

Comment: There are even shorter methods to read all contents of a file into a `List`, but it's not really a good solution. Why read the whole file into a list if the entry you search could be in the first line?

Comment: @magicmn - Yes the entry which needs to be searched can be on first line. But we wont be searching the same entry everytime, isnt it ?